# How to get DCount not working with dates in Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to use Dcount function to find if a record exists in the table.

The **primary key** in the ScadaHourly table is the **date**.

An example of how this would be entered is **“15/10/2013 1:00:00 AM”**

```
If DCount("Date", "ScadaHourly", "Date = " & Format(date1, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")) > 0   Then
 MsgBox "User Name Found!"
  Else
MsgBox "User Name Not Found!"
End If
```

How would I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Instade of the **dcount** i woule use **DLookup**

```
DLookup("FieldName" , "TableName" , "Criteria= #date#")
```

but to work with your code this waht you have to do:

```
If DCount("Date", "ScadaHourly", "Date = " & CDATE(date1)) > 0   Then
 MsgBox "User Name Found!"
  Else
MsgBox "User Name Not Found!"
End If
```

Comment: Thank you. That works. Now I need to change the table have a composite key. The composite key has two fields "Date" and "Station" in the table ScadaHourly. How would I be able to change the code to handle two criteria? ' DLookup("Date", "ScadaHourly", "Date = #" & date2 & "#" & " AND Station = H") –